# c explanation of preorder binary tree traversal

Tags: c, syntax

Okay guys, I would like to know the following comments I made in this code. Thank you,

```
void visit(tree_t *t){
    printf("%c ", t->e + 'A'); // why t->e + 'A', and not just t->e?
}

void tree_preorder(tree_t *t, void (*visit)(tree_t *)){ // i just don't know the parameter void (*visit)(tree_t *). what exactly is (*visit)(tree_t *)?
    if (!t) return; // what's the condition (!t)?
    visit(t);
    tree_preorder(t->l, visit);
    tree_preorder(t->r, visit);
}
```

Comment: tell us the definition of `tree_t`. We can help more then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a run down of the three questions.

```
printf("%c ", t->e + 'A'); // why t->e + 'A', and not just t->e?
```

This is making an ascii table assumption.

This will shift the character by 0x41 (65). So if you have a tree with an int range of 0 - 25 you can print out a valid character of A - Z

```
(*visit)(tree_t *)
```

This is a function pointer. It will be called on each node

```
// what's the condition (!t)?
```

This is a null check to make sure you are not at a leaf node in the tree structure.

Answer (score 1):

Probably t->e is in the range 0-26. By arithmetically adding the 'A' char, you get 'A' for 0, 'B' for 1, etc.

`void (*visit)(tree_t *)`
The argument is a function pointer to a function that takes a `tree_t` pointer as an argument and returns void.

Comment: Not really, you should SUBSTRACT 'A' then...

Comment: @H2CO3 No: `0 + 'A'` is `'A'`, `1 + 'A'` is `B`, etc...

Comment: ah, I see, sorry. I meant, if it was an index/subscript. You're right.

Answer (score 0):

```
void (*visit)(tree_t *)
```

is a pointer to a function which returns nothing and takes in a pointer to `tree_t` as a lone parameter.

```
!t
```

is one of the most preferred ways of checking for a pointer pointing at `NULL`. It means that you've reached the leaf node in the tree and you need to stop your recursion ( [base case](http://www.wisegeek.com/what-is-a-recursive-call.htm) ).

The adding of `'A'` may be similar to what we do in

```
if (isdigit(ch))
    ch = ch-'0';
```